# Ist it possible to fix aluminum tubing in a freezer?

Tags: repair

I own an upright freezer where I tried to drill a hole into the side wall. Unfortunately I hit one of the aluminium tubes that sit on the outside close to the metal frame of the freezer. Is there a way to fix it through welding or can I maybe put some plastic tubing in between and clamp it down?

Comment: Have you welded aluminium before? If not, you really don't want to start with your freezer. That's aside from the plethora of other problems you'll encounter on the way.

Comment: I'm a reasonably talented TIG welder who does aluminum.  That repair is nearly impossible.  Its sort of like welding beer cans together.  Folks do it in practice for bragging rights.  But to do it for true function, with only one set of parts... not I.  You might be able to flame braze a fitted patch over the hole, but even that's not an easy task.

Comment: It is possible to repair, flush and fill the system, but likely to cost several times the price of a new freezer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've already let out the magic smoke (refrigerant). It's not enough to just fix the tubing, you have to replace the refrigerant.

This isn't something you can do yourself. You'll have to call a refrigerator repair service that is qualified to work with refrigerant.

Note that the cost of repair may exceed the replacement cost of the freezer.

Comment: I was considering replacing it, my only problem is that the current freezer fits perfectly in a "niche" in my apartment. All the newer models are 2 inches wider it seems :(

Comment: @Andre I feel your pain! I bought a flat with kitchen furnitured around 49cm wide fridge. Of course it was an odd-ball: standardized size is 50cm with few low-cost models at 45cm. BTW: The 5 missing cms are equal to 2 inches. Coincidence? I think not! Look into budget models, they're often made in smaller sizes.

Comment: Air conditioning company could also help with refilling. The pipe needs to be definitely welded, glue or clamps can't hold the refrigerant.

Answer (score -4):

Cut that pipe using pipe cuter wer it is broken,then goto your nearest car spare parts and ask for quick clear glue then find a short peac of a pipe with a big hole than the 1 that is damaged even if  it is a copper pipe, use that peac to joing your aluminiam pipe using quick clear

Comment: I'm not sure this will be useful to the OP. Assuming you can fix the pipe, you still need to replace the refrigerant. The coils tend to be made of very thin pipe that is nearly impossible to cut, and may include fins that would block a patch. Since it's inside of the fridge wall, you'd also need to open that up just to get access, deal with any insulation, and patch the hole when finished. As others have said, this is not a diy job, and professional repair is likely more expensive than replacing.